# Hero Animation in polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement hero animation(from neon-elements) to animate to another custom element(element1.html to element2.html) by clicking a red square.

I wrote everything that is documented here:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation#shared-element

But nothing happens on click. Please guide me on implementing this.

Here are my files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js">        </script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html">
<link rel="import" href="element1.html">
<link rel="import" href="element2.html">
</head>

<body>
<template is="dom-bind">
    <neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="0">
        <name-tag>
        </name-tag>
        <name-tag1>
        </name-tag1>
    </neon-animated-pages>
 </template>
</body>

</html>
```

element1.html

```
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-shared-element-animatable-behavior.html">
    <dom-module id="name-tag">
        <template>

            <div id="hero" style="background:red; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; left:100px; top:50px;"></div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "name-tag",
        behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
        ],
        properties: {
            animationConfig: {
                value: function() {
                    return {
                        // the outgoing page defines the 'exit' animation
                        'exit': {
                            name: 'hero-animation',
                            id: 'hero',
                            fromPage: this
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            sharedElements: {
                value: function() {
                    return {
                        'hero': this.$.hero
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
    </script>
```

element2.html

```
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"> 
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-shared-element-animatable-behavior.html">
    <dom-module id="name-tag1">
        <template>
            <div id="card" style="background:red; width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; left:300px; top:100px;"></div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "name-tag1",
        behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
        ],
        properties: {
            sharedElements: {
                type: Object,
                value: function() {
                    return {
                        'hero': this.$.card,

                    }
                }
            },
            animationConfig: {
                value: function() {
                    return {
                        // the incoming page defines the 'entry' animation
                        'entry': {
                            name: 'hero-animation',
                            id: 'hero',
                            toPage: this
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

        }
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using wrong behavior. `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior` is for components who play or run the animation inside themselves. Very good example will be `neon-animated-pages` component, it implements `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior` because it runs animations inside.
2. Every item which placed in `neon-animated-pages` has to implement `NeonAnimatableBehavior`, not `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior`.
3. To run the animation we have to switch somehow between our animatable components. The "selected" attribute of *neon-animated-pages* help us with that. When `selected = "0"` `neon-animated-pages` shows you `name-tag`, when `selected = "1"` `neon-animated-pages` shows you `name-tag1` component.
4. You want to change view after click but I don't see any click event listeners. Add click events which will change selected attribute value and it'll work.